# Excel vba how to divide?

Tags: vba, excel

I trying to divide value taked from cells

```
Dim Sk as integer, P as integer

'Cells(5, 4) = 9
'Cells(5,  14) = 2

Sk = Cells(5, 4) - Cells(5,  14) 
' Sk= 7
P = Sk / Cells(5, "D") ' SK = 7 ' Cells(5, "D") = 15
' P = 0
```

But Excel give me P = 0 always if i change divide / by multiple * everithing ok

Excel want to be P as variant
Why this hapens?

Comment: It returns 0 because the answer is decimal (Integer type holds whole numbers only). Declare P as either `Variant` or `Single` or `Double` which holds decimals.

Comment: Go with the Variant if you don't know what the floating numbers mean :P

Comment: @mehow better advise would be go out there a _learn_ what floating point means rather than adopt poor practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of declaring as `SK` as an `Integer` declare it as a `Double`

Comment: While the answer does solve the problem it would be a much better one if you could explain why this solution will work.

Comment: Integer does not handle decimal type, so every division under 1 will give 0 as result. If you use Double as type, you will get Real numbers (decimals and all)